# converting from prototype to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I'm trying to do a simple ajax update of a div from a php file that gets data from a mysql database. One function populates the div, the other adds messages to the database and is called on click of a submit button. I was wondering if someone could give me their equivalents in jquery. Below are the prototype versions.

```
<script>
function getMessages(){
  new Ajax.Updater('chat','messages.php', {
    onSuccess:function(){
      window.setTimeout( getMessages, 3000 );
    }
  });
}
getMessages();
</script>

<script>
function addmessage(){
  new Ajax.Updater('chat','add.php',{
    method:'post',
    parameters: $('chatmessage').serialize(),
    onSuccess: function() {
      $('messagetext').value = '';
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [jQuery .ajax()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) call does it all.  It has wrappers with less parameters like .get(), .post() and .load() that you can use for less verbose syntax.

You don't mention what format the data you get back is in.  You need to specify in the .ajax() call.  Roughly:

```
function addMessage(message) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'add.php',
    success: function() {
      $("#chatmessage").text('');
    },
    error: function() { ... },
    timeout: 3000,
    data: {
      message: message
    } 
  });
 }

function getMessages() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'messages.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 3000,
    error: function() { ... },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#messages").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

**Note:** the dataType parameter just needs to match whatever the script produces.  If messages.php produces, say, an HTML list of messages then set it the dataType to "html".  If that is the case, you can also simplify the code to:

```
function getMessages() {
  $("#messages").load("message.php");
}
```

**Note:** the load() function is just a wrapper around .ajax().  Use .ajax() if you need to set things like timeouts, error handling, etc.  For example:

```
<div id="messages"></div>
<input type="button" id="getmessages" value="Get Messages">
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#getmessages").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'message.php',
      dataType: "html",
      timeout: 5000,
      error: function() {
        alert("Error talking to server.");
        $(this).attr("disabled", "false");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#messages").html(data);
        $(this).attr("disabled", "false");
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The above is a fuller example and should give you an idea of what you can use the extra parameters for.  If you don't need them just use the shorthand versions.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, but I'm pretty sure the data comes out as html. Is there something specific I'd have to change for that from the code above? You guys are really awesome with how fast you reply, thanks again.

Comment: Well your script (messages.php) will write its output in a specific format eg HTML, XML, JSON, etc.  The point of the dataType parameter is to match whatever your script produces.  If it produces html, set dataType to html.

Comment: No, the $(..).html() function updates the innerHTML of the element.  There shouldn't be a problem if the content returned is html it will be placed in the #messages div and parsed by the browser accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "messages.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(){
        window.setTimeout(getMessages,3000);
    }
});
```

for second addmessage

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add.php",
    data: $('#chatmessage').param(),
    success: function() {
        $('messagetext').value = '';
    }
});
```

for further details have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Comment: for addmessage, there seems to be something slightly wrong. So add.php also provides an updated query from the database in html format. on success, this is supposed to be put into the chat div. messagetext is actually the text area value sent to add.php. what would i need to change? thanks again.

Comment: oh very simple , just change the success function definition to this

function (data) 
{
  $('messagetext').value = data
}

while data will contain any thing that will be sent via ur response.