# What is the equivalent of Ajax.updater in Jquery?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Please let me know the equivalent of below prototype code in Jquery.

```
var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('abc', '/billing/add_bill_detail', {
      method: 'get',
      parameters: pars,
      insertion: Insertion.Bottom
});
```

I want to perform the same action using Jquery.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572161/converting-from-prototype-to-jquery

Comment: Read out this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Jai : i dont know much about jquery. So please post the equivalent code in jquery as answer.

Comment: @Pooja what is `abc` above? To me it seems that this is the siteurl.

Comment: @jai . jai its a id of div

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In jQuery the Ajax will use as following:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/billing/add_bill_detail",
   type: "get",
   dataType: "html",
   data: {"pars" : "abc"},
   success: function(returnData){
     $("#abc").html(returnData);
   },
   error: function(e){
     alert(e);
   }
});
```

Use #abc if abc is the id of the div or use .abc if abc is a class.

You can place the returnData iin your HTML where you want,

Comment: hi thanks. i will try this code any let u know whether its working or not.

Comment: var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('abc', '/billing/add_bill_detail', {. here abc is a div. i want to replace this div with the content in the add_bill_detail file.

Comment: wow. super its working.. :) thatnks @OSSCUbe Solution. giving +1

Comment: one more doubt. if i am replacing one div its working. but if i am going to replace one table its not working

Comment: the table is <table id='bill_details' align="center" class="body" width="100%" border=2> ..  and in script i given like this success: function(returnData){
                     $("bill_details").html(returnData);
                }. but its not working :(

Comment: `$("#bill_details").html(returnData);` use this. and you can ask more question or any doubt on my blog. it is : http://zenddevelopment.blogspot.in

Comment: in projotype i have given insertion: Insertion.Bottom like this for inserting rows. how to do the same in Jquery.

Comment: @poojaagarwal let us [continue this discussion in chat]. come here. (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26710/discussion-between-osscube-solution-and-pooja-agarwal)

Answer (score 3):

There are some ways using ajax like `jQuery.ajax({...}) or $.ajax({...})` other than this there are some simplified versions of these too like:

1. `$.get()` or `jQuery.get()`
2. `$.post()` or `jQuery.post()`
3. `$.getJSON()` or `jQuery.getJSON()`
4. `$.getScript()` or `jQuery.getScript()`

`$ = jQuery` both are same.

As you are using `method : 'get',` so i recommend you to use `$.ajax({...})` or `$.get()` but remember to include jQuery above this script otherwise ajax function wont work **Try to enclose the script in the `$(function(){})` doc ready handler**.

*`'abc'` if you could explain it*

Try adding this with `$.ajax()`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/billing/add_bill_detail",
        data: pars,
        dataType: 'html'
        success: function(data){
           $('#abc').html(data); //<---this replaces content.
        },
        error: function(err){
           console.log(err);
        }
      });
   });
</script>
```

or with `$.get()`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
      $.get("/billing/add_bill_detail", {data: pars}, function(data) {
          $('#abc').html(data); //<---this replaces content.
      }, "html");
   });
</script>
```

or more simply use the `.load()` method:

```
$('#abc').load('/billing/add_bill_detail');
```

Comment: var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('abc', '/billing/add_bill_detail', {.   here abc is a div. i want to replace this div with the content in the add_bill_detail file.

Comment: @Pooja just updated the answer. Even you can try this one: `.load()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .load() method

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched
>   element.

Read docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "abc/billing/add_bill_detail",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }

      });

   });
```

Comment: var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('abc', '/billing/add_bill_detail', {. here abc is a div. i want to replace this div with the content in the add_bill_detail file