# How to pass javaScript (jquery-ajax) variable back to php?

Tags: jquery

Can someone please help me, I want just to pass variable from java to php.
Some jquery code :

```
$('#').keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "get",
            data: some_data_to_send_to_url,
            success: function(data){
             var javaScriptVariable = data;                
            }
        });

      });
```

And I just want in the same php file do this :

```
$phpVariable = javaScriptVariable;
```

And then do some operations in php.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT :

Thank, but I don't have problem with data that is sent to  url:  "data.php",
This file receive some data, do some operation and return new data.
And I have problem with this new data “success: function(data)” that comes from this file, and I want to assign this data to normal php variable.

Comment: Didn't you just get `data` from the server? Why do you want to send it back?

Comment: Well, did you try it, and did it work ?

Comment: `$phpVariable = javaScriptVariable;` - You can't do this because the JS variable exists in the browser and the PHP variable exists on the webserver. But you're already using the `$.ajax()` method, which is one way of passing data from JS to PHP... (As an aside, Java and JavaScript are not the same thing.)

Comment: you can use the answer of the following post : http://stackoverflow.com/q/15565203/1035257

Comment: Thank, but I don't have problem with data that is sent to  url:  "data.php",
This file receive some data, do some operation and return new data.
And I have problem with this new data “success: function(data)” that come from this file, and I want to assign this data to normal php variable.

Comment: As already said, PHP runs on the server side. When you receive the data, you are at the client side and there is no PHP. You could send it back to the server by doing another Ajax call, but I don't know whether this is what you want/need.

Comment: Thanks for all help, I found solution.
I just put “data” that comes from ajax in hidden input. Then when user do something, this data from ajax is used to make different things.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) states :

> jqXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}); An alternative
>   construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces
>   the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for
>   implementation details.

### Javascript

```
var some_data_to_send_to_url = {"yourDataKey" : "yourValue"};

('#yourID').keyup(function() {          //Your "#" is not a valid selector
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "get",
        data: some_data_to_send_to_url,

    }).done(function(data){             //Updated
         var javaScriptVariable = data;                
       });

 });
```

### Php

```
$phpvariable = $_GET["yourDataKey"];
//Stuff
echo $yourReturn;       //This is what you sent == javascriptvariable
```

Anyway, as said previously, **PHP is server side exclusively**, and **javascript / jQuery is client side exclusively**. So you won't assign `data` to a PHP var on your jQuery's `done()`.

Answer (score 0):

refer this code to send data to php page as json object.

```
function send()
    {
    var ip=new Object();
    ip.session_id="312fdfwf1343r";
    var inputParam=JSON.stringify(ip);
    var module="module1";
     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                     url: phpurl
                         data: {inputParam:inputParam,module :module},   
                     dataType: "json",
                         success: function(msg)
                         {
                                 }
              });                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#').keyup(function() {
       $.ajax({
         url:  "data.php", // php file where you want to send data
         type: "get",
         data: {"some_data_to_send_to_url" : "yourValue"}, // this data will be sent
         success: function(data){
           // do something on success
         }
      });
  });
```

Then in your "data.php" file

`$data = $_GET["some_data_to_send_to_url"];`